# How to use a input:filetype into a ionic2 promp?

Tags: ionic2, input-type-file

I am trying to get a input of type file into a ionic2 promp.

thanks in advance!

i can't submit this because it is mostly code... so......... lets hop this is enough text then

How do i do this?

```
 addItemPromp() {
let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Toevoegen',
  message: "Vul de gegevens in",
  inputs: [
    {
      name: 'gewicht',
      placeholder: 'Gewicht in kg'
    },
     {
      name: 'Middel',
      placeholder: 'Middel in cm'
    },
     {
      name: 'Heup',
      placeholder: 'Heup in cm'
    }
  ],
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      handler: data => {
        console.log('Cancel clicked');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Save',
      handler: data => {
        console.log('Saved clicked');
      }
    }
  ]
});
prompt.present();
```

}

Comment: You can answer your own question to help others. But not by editing the question of course... If you think it won't for sure ever help anyone, delete it.

Comment: In that case i will remove my edit and just leave the awnser under it. Maybe it can help someone in the future who knows..

Answer (score 0):

It was actually very simple.. ugh..

just add a

type: 'file'

parameter to the object array